# Android - Change padding for viewpager side pages

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I need to create the following layout to my viewpager:
[image: viewpager]

I'm using PageContainer:

```
public class PagerContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

private ViewPager mPager;
boolean mNeedsRedraw = false;

public PagerContainer(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    init();
}

public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    // Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
    setClipChildren(false);

    // Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android
    // 3.x/4.x
    // You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
    // application targeted at these releases.
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate()
{
    try
    {
        mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The root child of PagerContainer must be a ViewPager");
    }
}

public ViewPager getViewPager()
{
    return mPager;
}

private Point mCenter = new Point();
private Point mInitialTouch = new Point();

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    mCenter.x = w / 2;
    mCenter.y = h / 2;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    // We capture any touches not already handled by the ViewPager
    // to implement scrolling from a touch outside the pager bounds.
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mInitialTouch.x = (int) ev.getX();
        mInitialTouch.y = (int) ev.getY();
    default:
        ev.offsetLocation(mCenter.x - mInitialTouch.x, mCenter.y - mInitialTouch.y);
        break;
    }

    return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
{
    // Force the container to redraw on scrolling.
    // Without this the outer pages render initially and then stay static
    if (mNeedsRedraw)
        invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
{
    mNeedsRedraw = (state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
}
```

`
And seting like this:

```
PagerContainer mContainer = (PagerContainer) mainView.findViewById(R.id.pagerContainer);
    pager = mContainer.getViewPager();
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pagerAdapter.getCount());
    pager.setPageMargin(getPx(20));
    pager.setClipChildren(false);
```

But the side pages has the same size of the active page.
I've tried to use pager.setPageMargin but only sets margim between pages.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a [PageTransfomer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) for that the changes the scale of the page on the left and on the right of the central one. When you implement the interface you'll be forced to implement the

```
public  void transformPage (View page, float position) {

}
```

page is the current `ViewPager`'s page, while `float position` is the position of page relative to the current center position of the pager. What you probably want is to change the scaleX and scaleY of page, when position is grater then 1 or less then -1. E.g.

```
public  void transformPage (View page, float position) {
       if (position > 1 || position < -1) {
          ViewCompat.scaleX(page, 0.75f * paget.getWidth());
          ViewCompat.scaleY(page, 0.75f * paget.getHeight());
       } else if (position == 0) {
          ViewCompat.scaleX(page, 1f);
          ViewCompat.scaleY(page, 1f);
       }
}
```

I have not the possibility to try it out so, please check for typo/cast.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working and something very strange happens. on the moment when the page scrolls all the background changes for other color and all pages disappears

Comment: I can't test it right now. Try with `Math.abs(position) * 0.75f * paget.getWidth()` and `Math.abs(position) * 0.75f * paget.getHeight()`

Comment: I've change the ViewCompat.setScale... to page.setScale... and now it works. But I have to put a condition 'if (position == 0) setScale(1)' again

Comment: yes sure, I completely forgot about that. Was the scale function of the position either ?